# Jenkins job scheduler

Tags: jenkins

How can I set Jenkins to run a job at a particular time?
Like if I'd like to set it to 8:30am every weekday and this is what I could do

```
H 7 * * 1-5
```

this randomly picks up 7:35am as running time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`H` is a pseudo-random number, based on the hash of the jobname.

When you configured:
`H 7`
you are telling it:

> At 7 o'clock, at **random** minute, but that same minute very time

Here is the help directly from Jenkins (just click the <kbd>?</kbd> icon)

> To allow periodically scheduled tasks to produce even load on the system, the symbol H (for “hash”) should be used wherever possible. For example, using 0 0 * * * for a dozen daily jobs will cause a large spike at midnight. In contrast, using H H * * * would still execute each job once a day, but not all at the same time, better using limited resources.
>
> The H symbol can be used with a range. For example, H H(0-7) * * * means some time between 12:00 AM (midnight) to 7:59 AM. You can also use step intervals with H, with or without ranges.
>
> The H symbol can be thought of as a random value over a range, but it actually is a hash of the job name, not a random function, so that the value remains stable for any given project

If you **want** it at 8:30 every weekday, then you must specify just that:
`30 8 * * 1-5`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.cronmaker.com/

```
0 30 8 ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI *
```

Answer (score 0):

30 8 * * 1-5

This would start at 8:30am Mon-Fri.
0 and 7 are Sundays.

Not sure what the H does but I am assuming it takes the lower case hex of h and applies 68 which is 35 in decimal... lol. Don't do that.

Following this format:
Minute Hour DayOfMonth DayOfWeek Day

Answer (score 0):

It picks that time because you told it that it can, as imagine you already know:

minute, hour, day of month, month, day of week.

Now you have user H which allows Jenkins to pick at random. So you have told it to run between 7-8 every  week day.

Change this to:

```
30 8 * * 1-5
```

Hope this helps!